# Starting a wine co-op

Tags: wine

I'd like to start a wine co-op for vineyards and winemakers in my local area. There isn't one.

The idea would be:
 - Help each other with growing problems, tips.
 - Share cost/expense of equipement.
 - Group discounts

Any tips on how to start such a thing?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is more business related than homebrewing.  You may want to ask your question at the [on startups](http://answers.onstartups.com) StackExchange site.

Comment: Too bad. I disagree.